# Embedding a tweet without media

Tags: api, twitter

Trying to get Twitter to embed tweets without displaying images or Youtube videos by default. I'm using the API endpoint: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/oembed and the flag `hide_media`. No matter if I set it to true or false, I still see media. Is there something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
data-cards="hidden"
```

to ensure no media is shown on you embedded posts.